"Incorrect inner plaintext: no content type" in SSL communication
Multiple computers works with the same application. And every day after few hour of work small part of them have a problem with handshake to external services.
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Incorrect inner plaintext: no content type
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:326)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:269)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:264)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:129)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1144)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1055)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:395)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.ensureNegotiated(SSLSocketImpl.java:709)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppOutputStream.write(SSLSocketImpl.java:962)
        at java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:81)
        at java.base/java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:122)
        at java.base/java.io.FilterOutputStream.write(FilterOutputStream.java:108)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.WireLogOutputStream.write(WireLogOutputStream.java:85)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.StringRequestEntity.writeRequest(StringRequestEntity.java:149)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.EntityEnclosingMethod.writeRequestBody(EntityEnclosingMethod.java:495)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.writeRequest(HttpMethodBase.java:1973)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:993)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:397)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:170)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:396)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:324)
        ...
Caused by: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Incorrect inner plaintext: no content type
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLCipher$T13GcmReadCipherGenerator$GcmReadCipher.decrypt(SSLCipher.java:1924)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.decodeInputRecord(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:262)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.decode(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:190)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:108)
        ... 24 common frames omitted

I've prepared tcpdump during problem and without problem, packets looks good. I don't know why error occured. Search in heapdump did not help.
The problem disappears after application restart.
Additional information:

application running on OpenJDK 11.0.7
OS openSUSE 15.2
problem occurs only on machines with old/weak CPU other machines never had a problem
problem detected only for service with TLS 1.3
when problem occured every request for TLS 1.3 failed
old apache.commons.httpclient and newest CloseableHttpClient has problem (same stack inside java)

Does anyone know a similar problem? What else could I check to find a solution?
Additional information:
After run JavaFlightRecorder problem with plaintext diseapear. I'dont know why.

Weird issue, could also be with the external services or with an in-between network device of course. I'm afraid that we cannot debug this from a distance. You can possibly enable tracing  for the TLS provider by setting the right properties at startup.

I would investigate the application for memory leaks or other resource leaks. Subtle memory leaks in the application or some libraries could gradually corrupt data relevant to SSL/TLS handling, causing seemingly random failures. Also investigate other resource leaks like connections etc.
Can you provide some more information on where this may be failing in the code?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I added some new information at the end
